# Как менять title кнопки

Tags: swift, button, storyboard

Всем привет! Хотел бы узнать, как сделать так, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку менялось ее название и  название сохранялось до следующего нажатия. Я пробовал создать булево свойство, и, в зависимости от его значения присваивать новый title для normal состояния, но у меня возникли две проблемы: 1)title обратно не меняется. Т.е., если я вместо паузы в title поставлю плэй, на паузу он не вернётся. 2) Значения меняются вне зависимости от условий. Я также пытался изменить state на highlighted, но, к сожалению, в этом случае у кнопки новое название не сохраняется, если я отвожу от неё мышь. Мне нужен противоположный эффект. Есть идеи, как это сделать?

---

После предложенных изменений название меняется, но кнопка паузы на симуляторе выглядит так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А код можете добавить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, можно использовать свойство `selected` кнопки. Оно похоже на highlighted, но пользователь только пользователь не может поменять его нажимая на кнопку. Зато мы можем.

```swift
// Код внутри ViewController

@IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    playButton.setTitle("▶️", for: .normal)                 // Задаем значение по умолчанию
    playButton.setTitle("⏸", for: .selected)               // Задаем значение после нажатия
}

@objc @IBAction private func didTap(_ button: UIButton) {   // Обработка нажатия кнопки. Не забудьте соединить стрелочкой из Storyboard или xib
    button.isSelected = !button.isSelected                  // Меняем значение selected на противоположное
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. А какое состояние выбрать, чтобы пользователь смог выбрать кнопку?  Я в документации смог найти описание только для .normal, .highlighted и .focused

Comment: Поправьте меня, если я не прав, но, по-моему, в состоянии .highlighted новое название не сохраняется

Comment: `highlighted` - это когда пользователь дотрагивается до кнопки. `selected`, которое я предложил - чтобы вы могли сделать кнопку выделенной, оно сохранияется. `focused` - это что-то про accessibility и Apple TV, я бы не стал его использовать. Если вам надо не только менять состояние кнопки play/pause, но еще и давать возможность "выбирать" кнопку, чтобы это ни значило, то это решение для вас не подойдет.

Comment: А подойдёт состояние .application для того, чтобы пользователь мог менять /выбирать название кнопки?

Comment: Ой, не знаю про application. Попробуйте. А опишите задачу про смену названия кнопки подробнее. Может быть я смогу предложить какое-то решение получше, чем запихивать всё в стандартные состояним.

Comment: Ну, мне это нужно для создания приложения с музыкой, где пользователь, по нажатию на кнопку, мог то воспроизводить, то останавливать музыку. Но с кнопкой я пока отдельно в storyboard работаю, чтобы подобрать правильное состояние для кнопки

Comment: А чем вам не подходит предложенный вариант с `selected` состоянием? Задайте для него значения в storyboard, а в коде меняйте `isSelected` при нажатии на кнопку.

Comment: Название кнопки, кстати, меняется, но только вместо названия одной из кнопок на симуляторе сине-белый фон

Comment: А по поводу состояния: я Ваш комментарий понял как то, что, при .selected, пользователь не сможет поменять название кнопки, если попробует нажать на неё

Comment: Сине белый фон скорей всего потому, что в настройках надо указать тип кнопки custom, а не standard.

Comment: Спасибо. Все работает

Answer (score 3):

Сам новичок, поэтому моё решение может оказаться пальбой из пушки по мухам, но как-то так:

```
@IBAction private func buttonWasPressed(sender: UIButton) {

    sender.currentTitle = buttonTouched == true ? "⏸" : "▶️"
    buttonTouched = !buttonTouched

}
```

Главное - не забыть связать метод-обработчик `buttonWasPressed` с кнопкой в **Interface Builder**'е

 
**P.S.** На всякий случай: всё, что идёт после `buttonTouched ==` называется *Тернарный оператор*