# Пустое пространство на кнопке

Tags: swift, button, tableview

Всем привет! Я хочу сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку воспроизведения ее знак менялся на паузу и производились определенные действия. Однако вместо паузы - пустая кнопка. Я думаю, ошибка может состоять в том, что я поставил if условия  в методе TableViewCell, где должен меняться знак кнопки, и при вызове в ViewController. Как сделать так, чтобы отображалась кнопка и при этом код TableViewCell/ViewController не переносился в другой класс? 
Код:

```
@objc @IBAction func playAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
playButton.setTitle("⏸", for: .selected)
playButton.setTitle("▶️", for: .normal)
playButton.isSelected = !playButton.isSelected
}
//ViewController
if button.isSelected{
let time = self.store!.setTime(duration)
cell.durationLabel.text = time
}
else{
let str = TimeFormatter().convertTimeToString(duration)
cell.durationLabel.text = str
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Исправил. Как отметил уже @Denis в вопросе  [Как менять title кнопки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1016965/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-title-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8), нужно было поменять тип кнопки с system на custom.